# How to remove inner bottom space (bottom margin/padding) of text/layout inside a SearchView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, searchview, android-search

So I got this SearchView that has a default space at the bottom for the text inside it. How can I reduce it (see the red lines in picture):

[image]

Comment: Try changing padding and/or text gravity

Comment: what theme(s) are you inheriting for your app theme?  You might be able to change this in a SearchView style...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Imagine you have `SearchView` named: `searchBar`

   ```
   SearchView searchBar = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchViewBar);
   ```
2. Get the view (`AutoCompleteTextView`) that holds the text inside your `SearchView`:

   ```
    //The view that contains the SearchView text
    AutoCompleteTextView searchTextContent = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchBar.findViewById(searchBar.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));

    searchTextContent.setTextSize(15); //Set the text size
    searchTextContent.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM); //Set its gravity to bottom
   ```

You can use AutoCompleteTextView methods such as setHeight(), setPadding(), and many more to manipulate this view. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).