# Get the textview inside of a SearchView with Xamarin for Android

Tags: android, xamarin, searchview

I'm currently developing an Android app using Xamarin.Android. In this app, I have a SearchView that I made smaller than the standard size. So, when I type in it, the text is too big to be fully shown inside the bar. I searched for this and found this link :

[How to remove inner bottom space (bottom margin/padding) of text/layout inside a SearchView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872724/how-to-remove-inner-bottom-space-bottom-margin-padding-of-text-layout-inside-a)

The person that made this post is looking for the exact same result than me, except he's not using Xamarin. I found similar posts, all for Android, with the same answer that seems to work.

I'm looking for the Xamarin equivalent to that answer :

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchTextContent = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchBar.findViewById(searchBar.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
```

As getContext(), getResources(), etc aren't existing in Xamarin, but probably have an equivalent way to get this AutoCompleteTextView.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: This should help you

you can use

```
Application.Context
```

or more specifically,

```
Android.App.Application.Context
```

instead of `getContext()`

for your `getResources()` make it `GetResources()`

So this is the solution:

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchQuery = searchBar.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Application.Context.Resources.GetId‌​entifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)); 
searchQuery.TextSize = 15;
searchQuery.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;
```

**Happy Coding**

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your post sent me the right way, and I had the desired result with these : 

AutoCompleteTextView searchQuery = searchBar.FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
            searchQuery.TextSize = 15;
            searchQuery.Gravity = GravityFlags.Bottom;

I mark your post as the answer, you can add those lines directly into it as I have trouble formatting my answer in comments. Thanks again !